# Subscribers not sent to

Tags: reporting, query, automationstudio

I had to get the report of bounced and not sent subscribers for a particular send in a automation studio.
I can get get the bounded subscriber from the _bounced DV, how can i get the Not sent subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Not Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5) [Tracking extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5) activity in an automation Studio. However, it is not a very well documented feature of Salesforce.

Alternatively, you could also try to subtract the bounces, sent, supressed(if any) from the target data extension and get an approximate count of not sent.

Comment: There is also a NotSentEvent SOAP API Object that you can use to gather this information. Please note though, this will not include anything that was scrubbed out before it would enter the send queue. Including malformed Email Addresses, etc.